# How to visually connect a numeric input and a table dynamically updating with the input?

Tags: tables, input-fields, range

[image]

**What I am building**: a search engine for gaming laptops. The #1 factor for gamers is, obviously, gaming performance, which is mostly judged by FPS – frame rate that a laptop runs a game on. Higher is usually better, but it's **very** non-linear and varies wildly between people, games they play, graphics quality they prefer, etc.

**What's on the screenshot**: filter option for the minimum tolerable gaming performance. You choose a number on a scale 0-100%, which corresponds to a *general, relative, abstract performance*. The table below gives *an equivalent* of that abstract performance *in real-life gaming terms*. You can read the screenshot as:

> "I am looking for laptops of **minimum 37%** relative performance score,
> which is equivalent to:
>
> - Playing GTA V at 66 FPS at Mid (medium) graphics quality, 62 FPS at
>   High, **AND BETTER**
> - Playing The Witcher 3 at 85 FPS at Mid graphics quality, 75 FPS at
>   High, **AND BETTER**"

The headers in the table are clickable — you can display more game / more graphics quality benchmark estimates by clicking on the respective game name / graphics quality.

The "37 % minimum" is a number input, but also works as a range input — you can click on the input, and either input the desired number, or drag a slider (that appears on click). **As you input the numbers, the numbers in the table adjust accordingly.**

**What feedback am I looking for:**

How do I make the connection between "relative performance score" and the "real-life gaming performance equivalent" table more clear? That changing the minimum performance rating through the numerical/slider input changes the values in the table correspondingly? Lots of people, even gamers, get confused at seeing this interface, even though (obviously) it seems extremely obvious to me.

Comment: Are the two figures **37** the same information? Why is it repeated?

Comment: @Danielillo yes, same information. Basically to emphasize that this table is **specifically** for your selected score, **specifically** to 37, and if you change it the table changes too. I've found some users be confused even at the phrase "Expected gaming performance for selected score:".

Comment: I suggest taking your users' input into consideration and exploring alternative options. I had to read your explanation multiple times to fully understand what you're trying to achieve, but your users may not have the same level of patience. Therefore, I recommend starting over and being more direct and concise in your approach.

Comment: @Devin thank you, yes I realize that. I've probably already tested 10 different designs. The reality is that, searching for a laptop is very complicated, much more so than searching for flights for example. Power users complain that there isn't even *more* technical info in the table; "noobs" complain that they don't understand the table at all. Thank you..

Comment: Is Gaming Performance Rating a primary criteria for customer? I mean is his search criteria sound like "I want laptop with GPR not less than 37%". It seems that price, graphics quality, fps and desired game are more primary criterias. Maybe providing user with traditional shop filters could be suitable for your case? As for now user have to find his real criterias using abstract one and this seems to be redundant step.